# How to make a base R scatter Plot from a data subset

Tags: r, plot, graph

I am using R Base plotting. I need to subset for two columns, whereby one where gender=Female and the other where Measure.Variables=Life Expectancy. Since the Measure.Variables column has two values "Life Expectancy" and "Mortality".

Moreover, I am trying to manually set the breaks and limits for the y and x axis and but I am unable to do so. I have attached a picture with the breaks and limits I want to add.

[image: graph picture]

Could you please help me with this also. I want to set the breaks for y axis to breaks=c(30,40,50,60,70,80) and for x axis as breaks=c(1900,1920,1940,1960,1980,2000). I want these limits to appear regardless whether data is available.

I am using the following code and its giving me an error when I add the second condition in the subset statement. Otherwise, it works fine without the Measure.Variables==Life Expectancy command.

Following is the output of the data

```
structure(list(Measure.Variables = c("Life Expectancy", "Life Expectancy", 
"Life Expectancy", "Mortality", "Life Expectancy", "Life Expectancy"
), Race = c("All Races", "All Races", "All Races", "All Races", 
"All Races", "All Races"), Sex = c("Both Sexes", "Both Sexes", 
"Both Sexes", "Both Sexes", "Both Sexes", "Both Sexes"), Year = 1900:1905, 
    Average.Life.Expectancy = c(47.3, 49.1, 51.5, 50.5, 47.6, 
    48.7), Mortality = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am using the following code

```
with(subset(LF, Sex == "Male", Measure.Variables == "Life Expectancy"), 
     plot(Year, Average.Life.Expectancy, col="red", pch=17,
          main="Male Life Expectancy", ylab="Life Expectancy"))
```

Edited in response to Adele, the y values still do not show. please look at this picture [Graph after Adele's suggestion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhc4R.png)

Comment: May I recommend you to consider a style guide, e.g. https://jef.works/R-style-guide/

Comment: @jay.sf thank you!! Could you also help with manually setting the breaks in R base plotting? I have years on x axis and life expectancy on y axis and the following are the breaks that I am trying to create
breaks for y xis =c(30,40,50,60,70,80)
breaks for x xis =c(1900,1920,1940,1960,1980,2000)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be fine with adding some arguments to your code and then using `axis()` :

```
with(subset(LF, Sex == "Male", Measure.Variables == "Life Expectancy"), 
     plot(LF$Year, LF$Average.Life.Expectancy, col="red", pch=17,
          main="Male Life Expectancy", ylab="Life Expectancy"
          ,xlim = c(1900, 2000), ylim = c(30, 80)
          , xaxt='n', yaxt='n'
          )
     )

axis(1, at = seq(1900, 2000, by=20), las = 2)
axis(2, at = seq(30, 80, by=10))
```

Comment: It still shows only 3 value for the y axis ie 1900,1940,1980. While the breaks work fine, the labelling does not appear for 1920,1960,2000.

Comment: i have added a picture to demonstrate as well if its not clear

Comment: please add `las = 2` to the first `axis` as I edited the code

Answer (score 0):

Easier to se the `data=` argument, and separate selection with `&` in `subset`. For axis customization, deactivate axis texts using `xaxt='n'` and `yaxt='n'`, and build your own with `axis()`.

```
plot(Year ~ Average.Life.Expectancy,
     data=subset(dat, Sex == "Both Sexes" & Measure.Variables == "Life Expectancy"),
     col="red", pch=17, 
     main="Male Life Expectancy", ylab="Life Expectancy", xaxt='n', yaxt='n')
axis(1, at=c(48,50,52))
axis(2, at=c(1900, 1902, 1904))
```

[image]

Note, that I used `"Both Sexes"` here, since `"Male"` wasn't included in your sample data.

Also, I used 40, 50, 52 and 1900, 1902, 1904 to demonstrate axis customizations.

In your case I would try

```
axis(1, at=3:8*10)
axis(2, at=seq(1900, 2000, 20))
```

Comment: thank you!! Could you also help with manually setting the breaks in R base plotting? I have years on x axis and life expectancy on y axis and the following are the breaks that I am trying to create breaks for y xis =c(30,40,50,60,70,80) breaks for x xis =c(1900,1920,1940,1960,1980,2000)

Comment: See update @MadiaKh

Comment: It is giving me an error "Error in plot.window(...) : invalid 'xlim' value" 
Graph1 <- with(subset(LF,Sex=="Male"& Measure.Variables == "Life Expectancy" & Race=="All Races"),plot(Year,Average.Life.Expectancy,col="red",pch=17,main="Male Life Expectancy",ylab="Life Expectancy",axis(1, at=c(30,40,50,60,70,80)), axis(2, at=c(1900,1920,1940,1960,1980,2000)) ))

Comment: @MadiaKh You seem to have misspecified `xlim=` somehow. `xlim=c(x1, x2)` has to be a vector with _two_ elements, try e.g. `xlim=c(1900, 2000)`.

Comment: Its not working for me. Is there any other way where i could just set the axis values manually? Also why doesnt the last value on the axis appear such as "52" in your case?

Comment: @MadiaKh Help me to reproduce your issue with a (not) working example, I'm, lost.

Comment: I am really sorry. Ill rephrase the question or add a new question for breaks with a simplified code.